# Backup mysql database on a different location

Tags: mysql, sql, import, export, backup

I have access to remote mysql only from my IP (CentOS OS) and I need to created a backup of database to a different location because its huge around 120GB. So right now I need some command to do that.

Will this commands work ?  If so what should I add after backup-file.sql to actually backup the file directly to a different CentOS server because my server doesn't have enough space.  Thank you

mysql> use db_name;

mysql> source backup-file.sql;

Answer (score 0):

**mysqldump -u username -ppassword db_name | gzip -c | ssh user@host 'cat > /backups/dump.sql.gz'**

it will send compressed zip file to the server

if u dont want it to  be compressed  then

**mysqldump -u username -ppassword db_name | ssh user@host 'cat > /backups/dump.sql'**

Comment: I have only 20GB space on my server while the db is 120GB, it will directly send it to the new server or it will be saved first because its not enough space, somehow I need to send it it directly. I'm not able to downloaded directly in destination server because IP its not allowed.

Comment: it will not save ,it will send directly to that server and save there for that u need ip access atleast hostname access